# scroll to with easing does not work with infinite js. scroll to with easing conflicting with infinite js

Tags: javascript, scroll, conflict, infinite

PLEASE VIEW SOURCE CODE ON BOTH PAGES.

On this page: _p1.html It is "page 1" Use the scroll bar on the right side of the browser to scroll all the way down to bottom of page. "page 2" will appear. I am using infinite scroll js.

I am also using scroll to anchor point with easing. Go back to top of the page again: _p1.html Click on "scroll down to item A" It scrolls down to middle of page with easing. Now, scroll down even more. Page 2 loads. Great. Now, click on "scroll down to item B" Item B just jumps to the middle page when it supposed to scroll with easing.

What is wrong? How do I fix this?

If you go directly to page 2 here: _p2.html Click on item B. You will see that easing works. BUT when on page 1 AND infinite js, the easing scroll does not work.

What is wrong? How do I fix this?

The scroll to js is fired off at page load and is not running again when new content is loaded into the page. Therefore the scroll effect will not work on any additional content loaded into the page (page2, page3, and so on). we need to find a way to re-trigger the javascript when new content is introduced and loaded into the page.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can attach the event handler to a parent, in this case I've used $(document) but to avoid excess overhead use the closest parent, then tell jQuery to only bubble-up the event to '.page-scroll'. This way if any new elements are added to the document which have the class `page-scroll` this event will be attached to them as well.

```
$(function() {
    $(document).on('click', '.page-scroll', function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        var $anchor = $(e.target);
        $('html, body').stop().animate({
            scrollTop: $($anchor.attr('href')).offset().top
        }, 2500, 'easeInOutExpo');
    });
});
```

**EDIT**

To make this work in your situation where the script may be included more than once, you have to make sure to only load jQuery, bootstrap and jasny once, then wrap the rest of the script in a `window.onload` event handler. as the window only loads once, if the script is included after the window is loaded it will not be executed.

I've also reduced the included jquery easings to only include easeInOutExpo which is the easing you are using in your function.

Replace **all** of the scripts on each page with the following script.

```js
<script>
if (typeof jQuery == 'undefined') {
    var newJQuery = document.createElement('script');
    newJQuery.type = 'text/javascript';
    newJQuery.src = 'https://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.1.1.min.js';
    document.body.appendChild(newJQuery);
    window.jQueryInterval = window.setInterval(function(){
        if(typeof jQuery != 'undefined') {
            window.clearInterval(window.jQueryInterval);
            var newBootstrap = document.createElement('script');
            newBootstrap.type = 'text/javascript';
            newBootstrap.src = 'https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.4/js/bootstrap.min.js';
            document.body.appendChild(newBootstrap);
            var newJasny = document.createElement('script');
            newJasny.type = 'text/javascript';
            newJasny.src = 'https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jasny-bootstrap/3.1.3/js/jasny-bootstrap.min.js';
            document.body.appendChild(newJasny);
            /******************************************
              Infinite jQuery Scroll
              @author Fabio Mangolini
              http://www.responsivewebmobile.com
            ******************************************/
            //location.href = 'index.html#start';
            var pages = []; //key value array that maps the pages. Ex. 1=>page2.html, 2=>page3.html
            var current = 0; //the index of the starting page. 0 for index.html in this case
            var loaded = []; //key value array to prevent loading a page more than once
            //get all the pages link inside the #pages div and fill an array
            $('#pages a').each(function(index) {
                pages[index] = $(this).attr('href');
                loaded[$(this).attr('href')] = 0; //initialize all the pages to be loaded to 0. It means that they are not yet been loaded.
            });
            //on scroll gets when bottom of the page is reached and calls the function do load more content
            $(window).scroll(function() {
                //Not always the pos == h statement is verified, expecially on mobile devices, that's why a 300px of margin are assumed.
                if ($(window).scrollTop() + $(window).height() >= $(document).height() - 300) {
                    console.log("bottom of the page reached!");
                    //in some broswer (es. chrome) if the scroll is fast, the bottom 
                    //reach events fires several times, this may cause the page loaging 
                    //more than once. To prevent such situation every time the bottom is 
                    //reached the number of time is added to that page in suach a way to call 
                    //the loadMoreContent page only when the page value in "loaded" array is 
                    //minor or equal to one
                    loaded[pages[current + 1]] = loaded[pages[current + 1]] + 1;
                    if (loaded[pages[current + 1]] <= 1)
                        loadMoreContent(current + 1);
                }
            });
            //loads the next page and append it to the content with a fadeIn effect. 
            //Before loading the content it shows and hides the loaden Overlay DIV
            function loadMoreContent(position) {
                //try to load more content only if the counter is minor than the number of total pages
                if (position < pages.length) {
                    $('#loader').fadeIn('slow', function() {
                        $.get(pages[position], function(data) {
                            $('#loader').fadeOut('slow', function() {
                                $('#scroll-container').append(data).fadeIn(999);
                                current = position;
                            });
                        });
                    });
                }
            }
            jQuery.extend(jQuery.easing, {
                easeInOutExpo: function(e, f, a, h, g) {
                    if (f === 0) {
                        return a;
                    }
                    if (f === g) {
                        return a + h;
                    }
                    if ((f /= g / 2) < 1) {
                        return h / 2 * Math.pow(2, 10 * (f - 1)) + a;
                    }
                    return h / 2 * (-Math.pow(2, -10 * --f) + 2) + a;
                }
            });
            /*jQuery to collapse the navbar on scroll
            $(window).scroll(function() {
                if ($(".navbar").offset().top > 50) {
                    $(".navbar-fixed-top").addClass("top-nav-collapse");
                } else {
                    $(".navbar-fixed-top").removeClass("top-nav-collapse");
                }
            });
            */
            //jQuery for page scrolling feature - requires jQuery Easing plugin

            $(document).on('click', '.page-scroll', function(e) {
                var $anchor = $(this);
                $('html, body').stop().animate({
                    scrollTop: $($anchor.attr('href')).offset().top
                }, 2500, 'easeInOutExpo');
                e.preventDefault();
            }); 
     }
    },1);
};
</script>
```

Comment: humble.rumble, Ive tested your answer on all browsers and it works. Thank you again!

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/78355/discussion-between-user2343800-and-humble-rumble).

Comment: I want to try a different infinite scroll js, this is a very similar issue. Can you please look at this issue here? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30360603/conflict-with-infiniteajaxscroll-js-and-bootstrap-carousel